# React native navigation redirects to previous screen automatically after some delay. How to protect

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am navigating from splash screen to the login screen on button click. On login screen after some delays it automatically redirects me to the back splash screen. How to prevent this automatic re-rendering.  I have not used any react native back function on login screen

My splash screen is:

```
<Button
  title="Log in"
  onPress={() =>
    navigation.navigate("AuthBase", {
      screen: "login",
    })
  }
/>
```

I have used the replace method on splash screen.
I want that when I move login screen it should not redirect automatically to the splash screen

Comment: Share the code you have in the `Login` screen.